# Count is increasing then decreasing back to zero. Want a cumulative count

Tags: python

```
def balloonBubbleCollide(balloon,bubble):
    point1 = balloon.getCenter() #get center of user controlled balloon
    point2= bubble.getCenter() #get center of select bubble
    distance= getDistance(point1, point2) #run distance foruma
    if distance <= 30: #if distance <= to 30, given my parameters, they are colliding
        return True

def checkForBubblesAbsorbed(balloon, bubbles, window):
    count = 0 #initial number of balloons absorbed
    for bubble in bubbles: #check each bubble
       collide = balloonBubbleCollide(balloon, bubble) #True or False, if colliding
       if collide == True:
           count = count + 1 #increase the number of absorbed by 1 upon collision
       print(count)
    return count
```

I guess these are the functions of interest. I understand why it doesn't work. Count is equal to count + 1 **only** when distance <= 30. How do make it a cumulative count, however?

Comment: It only counts `distance <= 30` because you have an `if collide` condition, and if count without any condition, then you're simply counting all bubbles and would get `len(bubbles)`, what is this "cumulative count" that you want?

Comment: @bakkal there are a number of bubbles. After it collided with the first, I'd like the count to rise to one. Then when the user moves the balloon to the next bubble, it rises to 2 - rather than fall back to zero and rise to 1 again when it collides with the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `return count` at every `for` loop, you want to `return` only once after the `for` loop is done accumulating the `count`

```
def checkForBubblesAbsorbed(balloon, bubbles, window):
    count = 0
    for bubble in bubbles:
       collide = balloonBubbleCollide(balloon, bubble)
       if collide == True:
           count = count + 1
       print(count)
    # This return should be outside the for loop (you have an extra indent) 
    return count
```

Note: You can just use `if collide`, especially since your function either returns True or None

### Accumulation

You can make a variable `cumulative_count = 0` outside the counting function (e.g. in the global scope in your .py module), then so `cumulative_count += checkForBubblesAbsorbed(...)`, that way the cumulative count is not reset to 0 everytime the function is called

```
cumulative_count = 0

def balloonBubbleCollide(...)
def checkForBubblesAbsorbed(...)

def somewhere(...)
    cumulative_count += checkForBubblesAbsorbed(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `sum` as `balloonBubbleCollide` returns a boolean, you need the total sum of the whole loop not returning after the first iteration which is what is happening in your own code as you have your `return` inside the for loop:

```
def balloonBubbleCollide(balloon,bubble):
    point1 = balloon.getCenter()
    point2= bubble.getCenter()
    distance= getDistance(point1, point2)
    return distance <= 30 # will be True or False


def checkForBubblesAbsorbed(balloon, bubbles):
    return sum(balloonBubbleCollide(balloon, bubble) for bubble in bubbles)
```

I removed `window` as it is not used in your function